# Django query aggregate upvotes in backward relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
Base_Activity:
    some fields

User_Activity:
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Base_Activity)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0) #Will be -1, 0, or 1
```

Now I want to query Base_Activity, and sort the items that have the most corresponding user activities with rating=1 on top. I want to do something like the query below, but the `=1` part is obviously not working.

```
activities = Base_Activity.objects.all().annotate(
    up_votes = Count('user_activity__rating'=1),
).order_by(
    'up_votes'
)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Count` like that, as the error message says:

> SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

The argument of `Count` must be a simple string, like `user_activity__rating`.

I think a good alternative can be to use `Avg` and `Count` together:

```
activities = Base_Activity.objects.all().annotate(
    a=Avg('user_activity__rating'), c=Count('user_activity__rating')
).order_by(
    '-a', '-c'
)
```

The items with the most `rating=1` activities should have the highest average, and among the users with the same average the ones with the most activities will be listed higher.

If you want to exclude items that have downvotes, make sure to add the appropriate `filter` or `exclude` operations after `annotate`, for example:

```
activities = Base_Activity.objects.all().annotate(
    a=Avg('user_activity__rating'), c=Count('user_activity__rating')
).filter(user_activity__rating__gt=0).order_by(
    '-a', '-c'
)
```

**UPDATE**

To get all the items, ordered by their upvotes, disregarding downvotes, I think the only way is to use raw queries, like this:

```
from django.db import connection

sql = '''
SELECT o.id, SUM(v.rating > 0) s
FROM user_activity o
JOIN rating v ON o.id = v.user_activity_id
GROUP BY o.id ORDER BY s DESC
'''
cursor = connection.cursor()
result = cursor.execute(sql_select)
rows = result.fetchall()
```

Note: instead of hard-coding the table names of your models, get the table names from the models, for example if your model is called `Rating`, then you can get its table name with `Rating._meta.db_table`.

I tested this query on an sqlite3 database, I'm not sure the `SUM` expression there works in all DBMS. Btw I had a perfect Django site to test, where I also use upvotes and downvotes. I use a very similar model for counting upvotes and downvotes, but I order them by the `sum` value, stackoverflow style. The [site](http://www.bashoneliners.com/) is [open-source](https://github.com/janosgyerik/bashoneliners), if you're interested.

Comment: I know that I can use `Avg`, I'm currently doing that, but the result is different. I want the look at up votes only, so disregard down votes. In my example, I want _2 up, 10 down_ to end up before _1 up, 0 down_. If I look at averages, it would be the other way around.

Comment: @jvannistelrooy I don't understand: `(2 - 10) / 12 = -0.66` is less than `(1 + 0) / 2 = 0.5` So what am I missing?

Comment: You're completely right, but for the view I'm building I want to disregard down votes, so the values would be `2, 1`, instead of `-0.66, 0.5`. Maybe my original question isn't clear, I'll edit it.

Comment: This will cause the query to filter all activities with a rating < 1. I want to get all activities (no matter the rating), but order them by the number of 1-ratings they have.

Comment: Hey janos, I decided that when it's this complicated, there should be a better way to do my models. I tried your last solution, but unfortunately the expression in the SUM() function doesn't work (I'm using postgres), even when I run the query directly on the db. I'm looking for a better way to do my models, but I'll except your answer if the SQL works, so others can benefit from it.

Comment: On a side note, I discovered there's a Django way to limit the Foreignkey field, and you can use Q objects for this. Maybe that's a way to solve this, but I haven't had time to look into it yet.

Comment: @jvannistelrooy unfortunately I don't have a postgres to play with. But that's an SQL matter anyway, not really django. I agree it's good to review your design. But sometimes it can be acceptable to use direct SQL queries like this, it doesn't necessarily mean poor design.